# Lexer rule not found from parser rule with Antlr4

Tags: java, parsing, antlr4

This question follows this one: [Using parser for OData v4 grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27202805/using-parser-for-odata-v4-grammar)

I made progress but I have an error and I can't figure out the reason.

A grammar `ODataParser` imports a lexer `ODataLexer`. I successfully generate the Java classes for both files

The lexer works fine and I can tokenize my string ("http://myhost.com/odata/Category(1)/Products?$top=2&$orderby=name"):

```
"http"         HttpOrHttps
"://"          ColSlaSla
"myhost.com"   Ls32
"/"            '/'
"odata"        'odata'
"/"            '/'
"Category"     ODATA_ID_CHAR8
"("            SubDelims
"1"            DecOctet
")"            SubDelims
"/"            '/'
"Products"     ODATA_ID_CHAR8
"?"            '?'
"$top"         ODataSignal_TOP
"="            SubDelims
"2"            DecOctet
"&"            SubDelims
"$orderby"     ODataSignal_ORDERBY
"="            SubDelims
"name"         ODATA_ID_CHAR4
```

Moreover the correct rules are associated with each token. I have the following error:

```
line 1:66 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting HttpOrHttps
```

After having enabled trace for the parser, I see these traces:

```
enter   odataUri, LT(1)=<EOF>
enter   protocol, LT(1)=<EOF>
exit    protocol, LT(1)=<EOF>
exit    odataUri, LT(1)=<EOF>
```

It seems that the problem occurs in the parser rule protocol. Here is an extract of the grammar rules (odataUri is the entry point I use):

```
grammar ODataParser;
import ODataLexer;

odataUri : protocol ColSlaSla host ( COLON port )?
       serviceRoot
       ( ODataSignal_METADATA | ODataSignal_BATCH | odataRelativeUri )? EOF;

protocol :  HttpOrHttps;

serviceRoot : SLASH ( segmentNZ SLASH )*;

odataRelativeUri : resourcePath ( QUESTION queryOptions )?;
```

Here is the corresponding part of the lexer:

```
ColCol : COLON COLON ;
ColSlaSla : COLON SLASH SLASH ;

HttpOrHttps : H T T P ;
```

Here is the Java code I use to parse the expression:

```
ANTLRInputStream in = new ANTLRInputStream(expression);

ODataParserLexer lexer = new ODataParserLexer(in);
ODataParserParser parser = new ODataParserParser(
                    new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
parser.setTrace(true);

// Errors catching
ODataErrorListener errorListener = new ODataErrorListener();
parser.addErrorListener(errorListener);

ODataParseListener listener = new ODataParseListener();
parser.addParseListener(listener);

OdataUriContext ctx = parser.odataUri();
```

Does anyone see something wrong in this.
Thanks very much for your help

Comment: You shouldn't use "import" in this case. It's meant to be used to reuse parts of a lexer in another lexer (or parts of a parser in another parser). Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299214/using-antlr-parser-and-lexer-separatly ; Maybe you could also post the complete lexer/parser files so they can be tested by others.